# Maps: Adding to the key of a value where the value is a list

Tags: java

So I have `Map<Node,ArrayList<Node>> G = new LinkedHashMap<>();` where Nodes map to a list of other Nodes. The idea here is that I am creating a graph.

However, when I go to add an edge to the map (graph) G, i.e

```
void addEdge(Node v, Node w){
    G.get(v).add(w);
    G.get(w).add(v);
}
```

I get a nullpointer exception. What baffles me the most is why the value of the key is returning null. When I add a node to the graph, i.e

```
void addNode(Node v){
    G.put(v, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

Does this not guarantee me that when I want to connect two nodes that there should always exist an arraylist as a value?

### Also, I am adding all the nodes in my graph before connecting them via addEdge.

Here is the piece of code of interest.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < temp.size()-1; i++){
                    G.addEdge(temp.get(i),temp.get(i+1));
```

### }

Temp is an "ordered" array where I stored other nodes that need to be connected, so 1-2,2-3,3-4...etc.. My testing suggests my temp array is fine and each element is indeed an instance of the node class.

EDIT - How would I make a good HashCode? I don't think it matters what order my keys are in?

Comment: could you show the full code?

Comment: It seems that your `Node` class is not implementing `equals` and `hashCode` methods correctly, which is essential if you want to use that class as the key of any map.